# remove array from multidimensional array

Tags: loops, for-loop

Javascript problem.
I currently have this array and I want to remove all sub arrays that contain 0's.

For example I have this array:

```
var changeReg = [
["PENNY", 0],
["NICKEL", 0], 
["DIME", 0], 
["QUARTER", 0],
["ONE", 0], 
["FIVE", 0], 
["TEN", 0],
["TWENTY", 0], 
["ONE HUNDRED", 100]
];
```

The end result should be this:

```
var changeReg = [["ONE HUNDRED", 100]];
```

My code:

```
  for(var i = 0; i < changeReg.length; i++) {
    for(var j = changeReg[i].length-1; j >= 0; j--) {
        if(changeReg[i][1] === 0) {
           changeReg.splice(i--, 1);
        }
    }
  }
```

Problem:
When I execute my code it gives me this error: 
TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined.

Comment: Any clues on a language?

Comment: @grail sorry bout that. It is javascript.

Comment: that is fine.  Just helps when people enter to know what they should be thinking :)  Also a good idea to tag it with the language ;)

Comment: @grail, yup I totally agree :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the functional way would be :

```
changeReg = changeReg.filter( function(item){
    return item[1] > 1;
})
```

Comment: I like this answer. So simple compared to what I tried to do. Thank you @nullqube